# gridview delete rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to delete rows from a gridview - but when I do it deletes current values from other controls in other rows.

After deleting random rows, I also get the following error.

`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

```
protected void gvShoppingCart_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //This is the method that responds to the Remove button's click event
    #region remove item

    if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
    {
        int rowid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //Response.Write(rowid);
        // Response.End();
        //Gridview1.DeleteRow(rowid);
        //Response.Write(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
        // Response.End();
        int rowIndex = rowid;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        { 
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");

                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");

                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");
                    TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox5");
                    box1.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();

                    box2.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();

                    box3.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    box4.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                    box5.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString();
                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(rowid - 1);

                /*dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"] = box5.Text;*/
            }

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataBind();   
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you change your debug settings to always throw exceptions what new information does this give you ? (Debug -> Exceptions -> tick the Throw column for the Common Language Runtime Exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

change your condition to...

```
if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 && dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > rowIndex)
```

NOTE:
are you sure e.CommandArgument is giving index of that particular row ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the e.commandargumnet is correct, it retrieves the rownumber, so i have to add -1 to get the correct datarow

it's when i delete several rows, the commandargument doesnt update